Express.js is not reading my req.session.user object correctly


const db = require('../config/db.js');
const { Request } = require('mssql');

loadForm = (req, res) => { 

    if(req.session.user.role === "admin"){
        console.log(req.sesion.user);
        console.log(req.session.user + 'is an admin');
    } else {
        console.log(req.session.user);
        console.log(req.session.user + 'is not an admin ');
    }
}
    



module.exports = {
    loadForm
    
}



I keep getting this output even when the role property is clearly defined:any suggestion on why the if conditional statement is not reading the role property. It actually worked a few times before I restarted the node.js server. Not it doesn't work.
  username: 'daniel',
  password: 'letmein1',
  role: 'admin     ',
  full_name: 'Daniel Medina'
}
[object Object]is not an admin 


Use , instead of + in your console.log(). Yes, that's right, console.log() accepts multiple arguments

Is this because "session" is misspelled as sesion?

Nah the issue is that the if statement is reading the .role property which is set to admin and yet it still isnt return a true value for some reason

You have whitepace after the word admin here: role: admin     ' therefore it wont be equal.  Do if(req.session.user.role.trim() === "admin"){ to check.
